# Rails ActiveRecord :joins with LEFT JOIN instead of INNER JOIN

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, join, left-join, inner-join

I have this code

```
User.find(:all, :limit => 10, :joins => :user_points,
                :select => "users.*, count(user_points.id)", :group =>
                "user_points.user_id")
```

which generates following sql

```
SELECT users.*, count(user_points.id) 
FROM `users` 
INNER JOIN `user_points` 
ON user_points.user_id = users.id 
GROUP BY user_points.user_id 
LIMIT 10
```

is it possible to make LEFT JOIN instead of INNER JOIN other way than `User.find_by_sql` and manualy typing the query?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

You can try this

```
User.find(:all, limit: 10,
            joins:  "LEFT JOIN `user_points` ON user_points.user_id = users.id" ,
            select: "users.*, count(user_points.id)", 
            group:  "user_points.user_id")
```

Comment: great, exactly what i was looking for

Comment: It's OK, but what's Jakub really expect with that? Users without points? If so, I think it need a `WHERE user_points.user_id IS NULL`, no?

Comment: @Kylo is there a construct in rails to create the left join without typing in a string?

Answer (score 40):

Just for future reference, adding `:all` gives a deprecated message. In later versions of rails you can simply chain the methods like this:

```
User.joins("LEFT JOIN `user_points` ON user_points.user_id = users.id").select("users.*, count(user_points.id)").group("user_points.user_id")
```

OR use a **scope** like this:

```
scope :my_scope_name_here, -> { 
        joins("LEFT JOIN `user_points` ON user_points.user_id = users.id")
        .select("users.*, count(user_points.id)")
        .group("user_points.user_id")
}
```

You can also chain `.where` between the `.join` and the `.select`.
Hope this helps someone in the future.

Answer (score 19):

Rails 5 has a [left_outer_joins](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-left_outer_joins) method. So you can do

```
User.left_outer_joins(:user_points)
```

or use the alias

```
User.left_joins(:user_points)
```