# ruby onrails join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to join my table in rails way.

this is the sql query

```
SELECT * FROM `ads` left join `state` ON ads.state_id = states.id
```

Answer (score 0):

[Rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables) is your friend=)

Answer (score 0):

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html

```
Student.joins(:schools).where(:schools => { :type => 'public' })
Student.joins(:schools).where('schools.type' => 'public' )
```

Or [Rails ActiveRecord :joins with LEFT JOIN instead of INNER JOIN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1509692/rails-activerecord-joins-with-left-join-instead-of-inner-join):

```
User.find(:all, :limit => 10,
        :joins => "LEFT JOIN `user_points` ON user_points.user_id = users.id" ,
        :select => "users.*, count(user_points.id)", :group =>
        "user_points.user_id")
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using rails 5 then you can use this -

```
Ad.left_outer_joins(:states)
```