# rewriting raw sql query with rails activerecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, orm

I am novice with rails and activerecord that's why sometimes I get problems like this one. 
I have mysql query:

```
select m.name, m.id, count(*) as count
from cars c
left join manufacturers m on c.manufacturer_id = m.id
group by c.manufacturer_id
```

which returns 3 values per row

how it can be rewritten using rails activerecord orm

*additional info*: `car belongs_to manufacturer` `manufacturer has_many cars`

Comment: duplicated (kind-of): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1509692/rails-activerecord-joins-with-left-join-instead-of-inner-join

Comment: let me add, however, that with Rails 3+Arel you can get you a prettier solution. Check: https://github.com/rails/arel.

Comment: thank you, tokland, I'll watch this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can :

```
Manufacturer.select("m.name, m.id, count(*) as count").
  joins(:cars).group(:manufacturer_id)
```

But you can also have a counter cache "cars_count" on your manufacturer attributes, or count with ruby (instead of with mysql) :

```
Manufacturer.includes(:car).each {|manufacturer| manufacturer.cars.size}
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't do the query in this way. You don't query tables but objects:

```
Car.count # the count on your query
Car.find_each do |car|
  # do something with car.manufacturer.name
  # and car.manufacturer.id
end
```

Comment: it requires additional sql queries and huge memory usage while I'm trying to do some optimizations