# Sum when object might be Nil

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, join, sum

I have the following line of code:

```
@ranking_array  = User.joins(:bets, :choices).select("users.id, sum(bets.profitloss + choices.profitloss) as total_pl").group("users.id").order("total_pl DESC").map(&:id)
```

This gives me an array of which ranking the users have - like user X is on 25th place and so on.

But the problem is that if the User haven't made any bets of any choices the the result will not include that user.

So how to fix the code, so it sums up the to profit loss even if either bet of choice is nil.

Solution:

Well.. It seemed that I had to combine your two answers to make it work :)

I needed the `LEFT JOIN` with the `COALESCE` so I got the following code which seemes to work..

```
@ranking_array  = User.find(:all,
                  :joins =>  "LEFT JOIN `bets` ON bets.user_id = users.id LEFT JOIN `choices`ON choices.user_id = users.id",
                  :select => "users.id, sum(COALESCE(bets.profitloss, 0) + COALESCE(choices.profitloss, 0)) as total_pl",
                  :group =>  "users.id",
                  :order =>  "total_pl DESC").map(&:id)
```

Thank you very much.. I've used all daytrying to solve this..

The problem is who gets the answer now it's a combination of the the two?

Comment: You could inject an if statment to convert any nulls into a zero to make sure that counts in the sum. As adding a zero will not change the total.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to use this one day too something like, look at COALESCE(something, 0) which will return one or the other. Hell i think you can add more options before 0, as it will continue down the line until 0.

```
@ranking_array  = User.joins(:bets, :choices).select("users.id, sum(COALESCE(bets.profitloss, 0) + COALESCE(choices.profitloss, 0)) as total_pl").group("users.id").order("total_pl DESC").map(&:id)
```

Comment: this solution is not db-agnostic, but works, save for the `INNER JOIN`

Answer (score 1):

I don't use Ruby myself, but you say you are "missing" rows for users who have not made any "bets".  That sounds like your actual query is generating an `INNER JOIN` and you need a `LEFT JOIN`.  See if [this SO answer helps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1509814/1275871).

Comment: beware ! remember that adding something to `NULL` gives you `NULL`. So if you have undefined fields, you have to cast the value (see @pjammer's solution)

Comment: Bob Duell : LEFT JOIN is works better.
@m_x : Without casting, only using LEFT JOIN, MySQL and Oracle gives either total or null when a player has nulls. e.g. x has historical bets among the records, but yesterday/today his bets are null. y has no bets at all so all null. Using LEFT JOIN, it returns x = 20, y = (null) . So I am curious to if you meant something else with 'undefined' as there are already 'undefined' fields in this (x,y) example.

Comment: im no sure i understand what you mean, what i just wanted to say is that if you want to do x+y, you have to do coalesce(x,0)+coalesce(y,0)  . given your example, if you do 20+null, you have null as the result, not 20.