# Active Record includes with where

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I'm having trouble getting the syntax of a query down:

I've got channels, which function like 'category' in a blog. I've got Shows which are like posts. A Show has a boolean 'approved' so it's true or false. Channel also has a position.. There are many shows to a channel.

How can I get all the channels by position order with shows that are only approved = true?

I tried this: `Channel.includes(:shows).order('channels.position')` and that gets me channels in the correct position, and although I can already do `channel.shows`, it's getting all the shows assigned to that channel regardless of whether or not the `show.approved=true`.

`Channel.includes(:shows).order('channels.position')` returns all channels and shows regardless of whether a show is approved.

`Channel.includes(:shows).where(shows:{approved: true}).order('channels.position')` returns only channels that have been approved, skipping channels that don't have approved content; but **I need the channels to return no matter what the status of a show, but with their shows to be empty arrays.**

Comment: You need to use an outer join.  Check this SO link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1509692/rails-activerecord-joins-with-left-join-instead-of-inner-join

Comment: You mean like this? `Channel.includes(:shows).where(:shows => []).order('channels.position')`

Answer (score 1):

I'd personally use Ruby (still need to sharpen up on some SQL):

```
channels = Channel.includes(:shows).order('channels.position')

channels.each { |c| c.shows.keep_if(&:approved?) }
```

Comment: Huh; and that doesn't do any more query overhead? Part of the problem I've run into (as a ruby newbie) is that I'm sending way too many queries using the default Model.all and just trying to clean up / speed up what I'm doing.

Comment: What I'd suggest is you monitor the log as you're performing to be sure. If `Channel.includes(:shows)` is producing too many queries, you can piece together your desired structure with `Channel.all` and `Show.all`.

Comment: Curious as well: looking at the railscast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/215-advanced-queries-in-rails-3?view=asciicast   could I also not have a scope for getting shows.approved? and do a merge?

Comment: Let me see if I can come up with a query. You're right, you can add a scope (which I'd advise anyway) and merge, but I'm sure this is possible with a single query.

Comment: I've jumped around a few different possibilities, but even when only joining `shows` which are approved, rails still insists on performing a `select *` query for the `Channel.shows` association. My above method only produces two queries, so that should be fine. You might get a better answer if you post a new question on how to reduce this to a single query (or try IRC).